# How to check progress of unattended-upgr process? Should I kill it?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, unattended-upgrades

I've been getting the following after running a `dpkg` command:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

After running (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/250853)):

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

I get:

```
                     USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/lib/dpkg/lock:  root       2591 F.... unattended-upgr
```

**How do I check the progress of this process?**

**What are the consequences, if any, of killing it?**

Answer (score 20):

You can see the latest entry in the log file e.g. /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log, try

```
tail /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
```

Comment: Also, on ubuntu 20, it may be useful to check update status of `sudo upgrade` command (e.g. when ssh connection freezes). In this case: 
`tail /var/log/dpkg.log`